# Tjovos Questions room: transform.localScale.x error: how to fix the error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, compiler-errors, scale

This is my Code:

```
transform.localScale.x + 0.1f;
```

Hehe, who would have thought it:

```
Assets\Test.cs(18,13): error CS0201: Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement
```

So, to the Question: I want to make a health bar. So a Cube with a texture should just change the Size in the x direction. But I get the error. How to fix the error? Greetings Tjovo studios.

Answer (score 0):

[`transform.localScale`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-localScale.html) is a [property](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties) **returning**(getter) or assigning (setter) a [`Vector3`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.html) which is a **struct**.

Changing a field/property value of that `struct` directly is a) not allowed (see exception) and b) it wouldn't have any effect since the setter of the property wouldn't be called.

You have to go

```
var localScale = transform.localScale;
localScale.x += 0.1f;
transform.localScale = localScale;
```

or if you prefer a one-liner (though eventually not that efficient)

```
transform.localScale += Vector3.right * 0.1f;
```

---

Though it is totally out of the scope for your question - please stick to the community rules in the future - one simple solution to make an object grow only into a certain direction is parenting.

In your case if you want to grow the health bar only from right (0) to left (1 or max) I would use a setup like

```
healthBarAnchor
|--healthbarVisualizer
```

and then make sure the `healthbarVisualizer` has a local position offset relative to the `healthBarAnchor` such that its left edge is at the pivot point of the `healthBarAnchor`. (=> `healthbarVisualizer.transform.localPosition = healthbarVisualizer.transform.localPosition + 0.5f * healthbarVisualizerWidth`)

This way whenever you scale the parent up or down the child object stays anchored with the left edge at the center pivot of the parent.

Comment: Thank you, and how do I make the size change only to the left?

Comment: Because your follow up question about an object growing into one direction only has nothing to do with the original question about your compiler error for the assignment of `transform.localScale.x += 0.1f;` You would usually do a new research and open a new question for that one specific question ;)

Comment: 1. I can't ask 2 questions on one day

Comment: 2. This was my question